# text replaces in DOM but previous text shows untill the DOM loads

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var datePublished = document.querySelector('[itemprop=datePublished]').textContent;
const span = document.querySelector(".powerpage-author-details");
var text_to_change = span.childNodes[3];
text_to_change.nodeValue =" / "+datePublished;
```

```html
<div class="powerpage-author-details w3_bg"><picture title="Top 10 Best Customer Service Value Certifications Top 10 Best Customer Service Coach certifications">
<source type="image/webp" srcset="https://some_image.webp">
<img width="450" height="450" src="https://some_website.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/circle-cropped-1.png" data-src="https://some_website.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/circle-cropped-1.png" alt="Top 10 Best Customer Service Values Certifications Top 10 Best Customer Service Values certifications" data-done="Loaded">
</picture>
&nbsp;<div class="w3_bg"><a href="https://somesite.com/author-anon-author/">Anon Author</a></div>/&nbsp; 9th July 2022</div>`

<div class="sai-bio" style="padding-top: 10px; display: inline-flex; align-items: center;"><picture style="width: 10%;">
<source type="image/webp" srcset="https://some_image.webp" />
<img src="https://some_image.png" />
</picture>
&nbsp;<u style="padding: 10px;"><a href="https://some_author/">Sai Blackbyrn</a></u>/&nbsp;10th April 2022</div> 

<span class="posted-on"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2022-09-13T11:51:58+05:30" itemprop="datePublished">13th September 2022</time></span> <span class="byline">by <span class="author vcard" itemprop="author" itemtype="https://schema.org/Person" itemscope>
<a class="url fn n" href="https://some_author//" title="View all posts by Anon Author" rel="author" itemprop="url"><span class="author-name" itemprop="name">Anon Author</span></a></span></span> </div>
```

Here 9th July 2022 is correctly replaced by 13th September 2022.
But the issue is untill the page loads it shows old text (9th July 2022) after page loads it shows replaced text i.e. new text (13th September 2022)

Comment: Your snippet doesn't appear to do what your saying, it's likely your using some onload event, or your loading your script with `defer` options etc, but the Snippet here is likely using some form of script injection.  You might find you don't require to wait for the onload event of the page and place your script at the bottom of your `body` tag,.. eg..  `<body>Website<script>code</script></body>`

Comment: an element can only be selected by JS if the element already exists. Either do it server-sided or hold the rendering, apply changes through JS, and then display the website. Alternativly add the script that applies the changes directly in the body after that element